# Which component should own the state among multiple components in React App?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Application is segregated into multiple components and one of the components can have the state. So that it can be passed to rest of the components as props. My doubt is

What are the things to be considered to elect some particular component to have the state?

Comment: it should be parent component of others components.

Comment: you have used 'redux' tag. if you are using redux, you can access any part of your store as props, inside any of your components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice tip to managing state without any libraries (redux, flux, mobx, whateverx) - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

The main point is components communication. Parent to child via props, child to parent via callbacks.